# Remove repeated chars completely (regex/C#)

Tags: c#, regex

Looking for a one line C# code that would remove repeated chars from a string.
Have done it with a simple loop with look-ahead but like to see a regex soln.
Ex.
input =  "6200032111623451123345666"
output = "623262345245"

Thanks.

Lyle

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
string s = Regex.Replace("6200032111623451123345666", @"(.)\1+", "");
```

The `\1+` is "one or more" (greedy) of the back-reference to the first capture-group, `.` (any character).

Answer (score -1):

s/(([a-zA-z0-9])\1+)//g  of course you need  to translate it to c#

Comment: It should be `(([a-zA-z0-9])\2+)`. `\1` is the outermost parenthetic group (which is the whole string in this case).